# Play framework and small app

Tags: scala, playframework, load, program-entry-point

I have a Play framework app in Scala. It uses database and I need to load data into database before first app start. I thought I could add a class with a main class in the app and start it like `play -main loadDataClass`. It seems to be working but once I access `Play.current.configuration` I need this to access database credentials. I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application

Please advice how to implement this. Should I somehow start the application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module for loading data on start up. In the production mode (*activator start*) it would run after application start, in the development mode (*activator run*) it would run after first request to the server.

Create module

```
app/modules/PrepareDatabaseModule.scala:
```

inside this module

```
package modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

trait PrepareDatabase {}

class PrepareDatabaseClass extends PrepareDatabase {
  initialize() 
  def initialize() = {
    // Load your data here
  }
}

class PrepareDatabaseModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[PrepareDatabase])
      .to(classOf[PrepareDatabaseClass]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

in *conf/application.conf*:

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.PrepareDatabaseModule"
```

Comment: I want to call the code before my app is used. I want to run this from command line. Is this possible with Play or should I make a separated app for this?

Comment: You scenario sounds very strange for me. I would create special simple java app for this, like you describe, with main method, and run it from shell script and then run play. I still believe that your task could be resolved with play plugin.